# dial tcp: lookup xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: no such host

Tags: networking, docker, automation

Trying to push an docker image to private docker repository. but getting error like:  `"dial tcp: lookup xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: no such host"`. 
I have logged in correctly to the repository and build succeeded.

The following command using to push the image to private `repo: 
sud docker push x.x.x.x:446/dns/graphs`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Editing the DNS nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf` file helped me.

Change your existing nameserver to google nameserver i.e., x.x.x.x to 8.8.8.8

Comment your nameserver IP and add something like this :

```
#nameserver x.x.x.x
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

should work.

Comment: That did indeed work...thank you. Any idea why Google Cloud Shell is configured with a different nameserver than 8.8.8.8? The nameserver that is configured in resolve.conf by default is unreachable.

Comment: Introduction to Google Public DNS: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/intro

Comment: I had this issue when creating a cluster on kubernetes and know it's resolved with this answer.

Comment: I had this issue using Doppler. it works like a charm

Answer (score 8):

If you are behind a proxy, this could be your issue. In this case, you need to configure the Docker daemon (not the client) proxy settings. You can do that by:

1. Create a systemd drop-in directory for the docker service:

   - `sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d`
2. Create a file called /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf that adds the HTTP_PROXY environment variable:

   - `[Service]
     Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/"`
3. Flush changes

   - `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
4. Restart docker daemon

   - `sudo systemctl restart docker`

Reference: [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was because of a typo mistake.

I wrote for example:

my-registry**hob**.mydomain.com

instead of:

my-registry**hub**.mydomain.com

Check for typo mistake..

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this issue because we had a private module and I didn't configure private module environment variables.
Adding these fixed my issue:

```bash
export GOPRIVATE="*.company.com"            
export GOPROXY=athens.company.com
export GONOSUMDB="*.company.com"
```

More details at: https://go.dev/ref/mod#private-modules

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the domain name which you are using for your private repo is expired, that is why it is not resolving through global DNS 8.8.8.8 . Check with your Domain name provider.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error, and my problem was that I mistyped the registry url puting '.co' instead of '.com' at the end of host:

What I wrongly typed: *********.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.**co**

What shold be: *********.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.**com**

Causing to be a host that really doesn't exist. Always check it twice.

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue `dial tcp: lookup abc.com on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host`.

Issue resolved when

> Turn off the **VPN**