# Cross Container Communication from this docker-compose not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Inmy project, I have three services

1. redis
2. service-1
3. service-2

Here is the docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

services:

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

  service-1:
    image: service-1-latest
    ports:
      - 7002:7002
    depends_on:
      - redis


  service-2:
    image: service-2-latest
    ports:
      - 7000:7000
    restart: on-failure:5
```

service-2 communicate with service-1 like 
http://service-1:7002/v1/reg/registerservice

But on doing that, I see following message on logs :

**dial tcp: lookup service-1 on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host**

**I tried several ways by following on stack-overflow and docker documentation, but cross-container communication didn't work, First I tried on MacOs and then on Linux and didn't work. In my case, One container (service-2) calls others rest-end-points(e.g. service-1).**

**Operating System Details** : Linux staging 4.15.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 6 11:12:41 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**Docker Version** : Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89

---------- Reference---------------------------

I followed this document to do the above : https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

which says the following :

For example, suppose your app is in a directory called myapp, and your docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "8001:5432"
```

When you run docker-compose up, the following happens:

A network called myapp_default is created.
A container is created using web’s configuration. It joins the network myapp_default under the name web.
A container is created using db’s configuration. It joins the network myapp_default under the name db.

Comment: Did you ever run "docker-compose down"? If not, try it. It will remove the network which created by compose. The incorrect network may cause this. docker network ls will list all network, you can check them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45011909/10354937

Editing the DNS nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf` file helped me.

Change your existing nameserver to google nameserver i.e., x.x.x.x to 8.8.8.8

Comment your nameserver IP and add something like this :

```
#nameserver x.x.x.x
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

should work.

Comment: I tried but It didn't work, Means tried many many different other ways as well, may be I am doing some other basic mistakes !