# Deploying back end java app to ibm cloud kubernates

Tags: java, kotlin, kubernetes, ibm-cloud, backend

I,m trying to deploy a backend java app to ibm cloud and i'm getting this error`FAILED
Failed to generate the required files. Please try again.

Could not get list of available Starter Kits. Please try again.
[Get https://us-south.devx.cloud.ibm.com/appmanager/v1/starters?tag=notDeveloperConsole: dial tcp: lookup us-south.devx.cloud.ibm.com on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host]
`
Please note the app is written in kotlin and ktor

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Ahmed Kamar. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question. At the moment, it's missing details that can help us help you.

Comment: Can you share the exact command you were trying when you got this response? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> dial tcp: lookup us-south.devx.cloud.ibm.com on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host

Looks like your dns server is not working.
Try using different dns server.

Look at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33893150/dial-tcp-lookup-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-no-such-host/53848018)