# Docker on localhost error: dial tcp: lookup localhost on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm having this error when starting a docker service, the full error message says:

```
FATA[0000] version check: failed to get version from server: failed making version api call: Get "http://localhost:8080/v1/version": dial tcp: lookup localhost on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
```

I've done already what's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33893150/dial-tcp-lookup-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-no-such-host) but nothing seems to work, and I dont clearly understand what's going on here :(

Answer (score 4):

You can try two approaches to resolve this:

1. Try to change localhost to 127.0.0.1
2. Check your etc/hosts file to see if there is an entry for localhost. If there isn't any, just add it as follows:

`vim /etc/hosts`

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost  <- add this line
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want access host's localhost. you should change

`localhost` to `host.docker.internal`

docker's localhost is container localhost.