# Why Cannot call web site Django with sub domain name

Tags: python-3.x, django, iis, deployment

I got the trouble for deployment Django app on IIS server, it is about the host IP/subdomain for the Django web application on the intranet.

**This IP has been created record in the DNS server on the intranet already.
but this website can’t be requested by subdomain name, Yet I can call web site by IP successfully. IP and domain name mapping is 17x.xxx.xx.48 = es-xxx.xxx.com**

This is an error, you can see The error on the left-hand side of this screenshot below.

**dial tcp: lookup es-xxx.xxxx.com on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host**

I used to develop ASP.NET and deploy on IIS Server, there is no problem with this issue.

[image]

This is my configuration both in settings.py and IIS server. I already attempted to use nslookup and it is fine as the figure below.

[image]

Comment: You can use the same error as a reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33893150/dial-tcp-lookup-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-no-such-host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33893150/dial-tcp-lookup-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-no-such-host).