# Upload image fails with error "dial tcp: lookup api.cloudinary.com: no such host"

Tags: go, cloudinary

I have been trying to upload to cloudinary via golang sdk. but sometimes it seems to fail after several requests (sometimes it works, other times it doesn't).

I run the app in localhost (windows) and without vpn.

error message:

> "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dd6mdlpgj/auto/upload": dial tcp: lookup api.cloudinary.com: no such host

```
type cloudinaryStorageRepository struct {
    cld *cloudinary.Cloudinary
}

func NewCloudinaryStorageRepository(cloudName string, apiKey string, apiSecret string) domain.StorageRepository {
    cld, err := cloudinary.NewFromParams(cloudName, apiKey, apiSecret)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return &cloudinaryStorageRepository{cld}
}

func (c *cloudinaryStorageRepository) Upload(ctx context.Context, storage *domain.Storage) (string, error) {
    file, err := storage.File.Open()
    defer func(file multipart.File) {
        err := file.Close()
        if err != nil {
            logrus.Error(err)
        }
    }(file)

    if err != nil {
        logrus.Error(err)
        return "", err
    }

    uploaded, err := c.cld.Upload.Upload(ctx, file, uploader.UploadParams{
        Folder:   storage.Folder,
        PublicID: storage.Name,
    })
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Error(err)
        return "", err
    }
    return uploaded.SecureURL, nil
}
```

Comment: You could check out [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33893150/dial-tcp-lookup-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-no-such-host) with regard to the possible resolution of your case.